# NotifyPropertyChanged on dependent properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, postsharp

I have the following view model

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class ActivateViewModel
{
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool ActivateButtonEnabled { get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password); } }
    ...
}
```

In my view I'm trying to enable/disable a button depending on whether a password textbox has a value or not.

`ActivateButtonEnabled` is not being notified automatically when the `Password` property changes. What am I doing wrong? I was reading [this article](http://doc.postsharp.net/inotifypropertychanged-dependencies) and if I understand correctly PostSharp should be able to handle dependent properties automagically.

Comment: This should work with PS out of the box. Please, could you post your xaml here? What kind of project are you using (wpf, silverlight, WP, etc...)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to access the password as 'this.Password' as PostSharp expects the 'this' accessor before all dependant properties.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the `ICommand` interface. The interface contains [ICommand.CanExecute Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that determines whether the command can execute in its current state. An instance of `ICommand` interface can be bound to the `Command` property of the `Button` instance. If the command can not be executed, the button will be disabled automatically.

The `ICommand` interface implementation which has `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`-like method must be used to achieve the described behavior, for example:

- `DelegateCommand` class from Prism library.
- `RelayCommand` from MVVM Light library.
- etc.

The implementation of `ViewModel` using `DelegateCommand` class from Prism library:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class ActivateViewModel
{
    private readonly DelegateCommand activateCommand;
    private string password;

    public ActivateViewModel()
    {
        activateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Activate, () => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password));
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set
        {
            password = value;
            activateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); // To re-evaluate CanExecute.
        }
    }

    public ICommand ActivateCommand
    {
        get { return activateCommand; }
    }

    private void Activate()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

XAML-code:

```
<Button Content="Activate"
        Command="{Binding ActivateCommand}" />
```

Have not found the documentation about PostSharp's `ICommand`-interface support, but a question: [INotifyPropertyChanged working with ICommand?, 
PostSharp Support](http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/questions/398-inotifypropertychanged-working-with-icommand).

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but it seems silly to pull in prism and go out of my way for something that should work out of the box with the tools that I currently have.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan, sure, Prism library is used just for example. Another suitable `ICommand` interface implementation can be used (other libraries) or created in the current solution (project). The answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

In the view, what control are you using? a PasswordBox? is posible that the property password is never updated.

The Passwordbox.Password is not a dependency property for security reasons, and then, not supports bindings. You have an explanation and a possible solution in:

http://www.wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html

If the control is not a passwordbox, can you write us the view?

Comment: I was using an event handler for passwordchanged event and then manually setting `Password` within the handler, but I also tried using a regular textbox without the changed handler and it still didn't work.

Comment: The view is simple. `Textbox text="{Binding Path=Password}"` and `Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ActivateEnabled}"`